# Stanford Parser - MultiThreading issue - LexicalizedParser

Tags: java, multithreading, nlp, stanford-nlp

Firstly, parsing is running smooth on small set of sentences - In order of 200ms to 1s - depending on the sentence size.

What do I want to achieve?

I want to parse 50L sentences in 1-2 hours.

Somehow, I need to convert this ->

```
            for(String sentence: sentences){
               Tree parsed = AnalysisUtilities.getInstance().parseSentence(job).parse;
            }
```

into multithreaded calls.
I wrote a multi threaded executor to do this, which looks like this ->

```
                MultiThreadExecutor<String> mte = new MultiThreadExecutor<String>(2, new JobExecutor<String>() {
                @Override
                public void executeJob(String job) {
                    Tree parsed = AnalysisUtilities.getInstance().parseSentence(job).parse;
                    inputTrees.add(parsed);
                }
            }, "");


            for(String sentence: sentences){
                mte.addJob(sentence);
            }
```

**It works fine on one thread**, but as soon as I give multiple threads it breaks with a exception inside the Stanford parse function. Exception looks like this ->

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:441)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.initRulesWithWord(BaseLexicon.java:300)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.isKnown(BaseLexicon.java:160)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.ruleIteratorByWord(BaseLexicon.java:212)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.initializeChart(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1299)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:388)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:234)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:189)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.AnalysisUtilities.parseSentence(AnalysisUtilities.java:262)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:147)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:144)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.MultiThreadExecutor$1.run(MultiThreadExecutor.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Dependencies not equal: "Spacious/CD" -> ".*./CC" left 0 and "Spacious/CD" -> "easy/RB" right 1
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.MLEDependencyGrammar.probTB(MLEDependencyGrammar.java:586)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.MLEDependencyGrammar.scoreTB(MLEDependencyGrammar.java:511)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.AbstractDependencyGrammar.scoreTB(AbstractDependencyGrammar.java:229)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustiveDependencyParser.parse(ExhaustiveDependencyParser.java:322)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:244)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:189)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.AnalysisUtilities.parseSentence(AnalysisUtilities.java:262)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:147)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:144)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.MultiThreadExecutor$1.run(MultiThreadExecutor.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BiLexPCFGParser.projectHooks(BiLexPCFGParser.java:342)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BiLexPCFGParser.processEdge(BiLexPCFGParser.java:546)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BiLexPCFGParser.processItem(BiLexPCFGParser.java:571)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BiLexPCFGParser.parse(BiLexPCFGParser.java:854)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:255)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:189)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.AnalysisUtilities.parseSentence(AnalysisUtilities.java:262)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:147)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.QuestionAsker$1.executeJob(QuestionAsker.java:144)
>       at edu.cmu.ark.MultiThreadExecutor$1.run(MultiThreadExecutor.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is there any way to do it ? I can relate to a previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286597/stanford-parser-multithread-usage) but to no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example command that will run the parser in multi-threaded mode:

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -parse.nthreads 4 -ssplit.eolonly -file some-sentences.txt -outputFormat text
```

Comment: You can run a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline in your Java code as well, here is some documentation on doing that: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: Be sure to get the new Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0 !